# More detailed weight painting?

Tags: modeling

Hi i was weight painting for a finger and I couldn't help but notice it doesn't paint anything until i hit a certain spot and even then it paints all around it!

apparently brush size doesn't help. any ideas?

Comment: add more vertices

Comment: Weight paint works similar to vertex paint, in that they are stored on the vertex. So you'll need to have a certain mesh density in order to achieve the detailed results.

Answer (score 1):

Weight paining is actually just assigning weights to vertices.  So you will need to add more geometry to your mesh.  I would recommend going into edit mode on your mesh, selecting all with <kbd>A</kbd>, and hitting <kbd>W</kbd> > *subdivide* or *subdivide smooth*.